vscode linux UI border menu issue
I am using Linux Ubuntu LTS 24.04 with BSPWM, SXHKD, PICOM, POLYBAR, on VMware Pro. When I click on any menu, it has a border around it that is white and a little blurry. How can I solve it? I want to delete it
I tried to modify picom but I can't fix it


Please rewrite in english

This is an English only site. Non English is off topic.

it's my first time here, i didn't know that is English only
